# MySQL export table to text file fields name

Tags: mysql, export

let's say I have the following table in `MySQL`

```
create table test_tbl
(
  col1 varchar(100),
  col2 varchar(100),
  amount int,
  created datetime
)
```

Data insert

```
Insert into test_tbl values('unu', 'doi', 10, '05/01/2015');
Insert into test_tbl values('patru', trei', 400, '04/01/2015');
```

I need export all the data from that table in the following format. The file should be txt file.

```
"col1"="unu","col2"="doi","amount"="10","created"="05/01/2015"
"col1"="patru","col2"="trei","amount"="400","created"="04/01/2015"
```

So the logic is:
Each column name with value separated by comma.

Does it possible get such result in `MySQL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For export the table's data-

```
SELECT  CONCAT('"col1"="',col1,'","col2"="',col2,'","amount"="',amount,'","created"="',DATE_FORMAT(created,'%d/%m/%Y'),'"') t  FROM test_tbl INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.txt' CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

For import the table from csv

```
    mysql> CREATE TABLE `test_tbl` (
    ->   `col1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `col2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `amount` int DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.44 sec)

mysql> load data local infile 'test.txt' into table test_tbl fields terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' lines terminated by '\r\n' (@col1, @col2,@col3,@col4)
    -> set col1 = substr(@col1,8), col2 = substr(@col2,8), amount = substr(@col3,10), created = str_to_date(substr(@col4,11), '%d/%m/%Y');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test_tbl;
+-------+------+--------+---------------------+
| col1  | col2 | amount | created             |
+-------+------+--------+---------------------+
| unu   | doi  |     10 | 2015-01-05 00:00:00 |
| patru | trei |    400 | 2015-01-04 00:00:00 |
+-------+------+--------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work.

Use `CONCAT` to build a string like this

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('"col1"="',col1,'","col2"="',col2,'","amount"="',amount,'","created"="',created,'"') t 
FROM test_tbl;
```

Then you can also dump it to a text file using `INTO OUTFILE`.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('"col1"="',col1,'","col2"="',col2,'","amount"="',amount,'","created"="',created,'"') t 
FROM test_tbl
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/yourtextfile.txt'
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Since `CONCAT` only has 1 row, you dont need to enclose any columns/fields with value since they are customised. Only a line break is used to terminate each `ROW`.

Hope it works!